# Oracle ODB.NET, Visual Studio 2012 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I created an Oracle DB. But when i tried to connect it with my Visual Studio 2012, it gave me the **same errors** all the time. What can i do about that situation. I looked up all the net.

Thanks for help!

**Error Codes Are(Tried with "Data Source Name" section)**

```
- When i tried with "ORCL": "ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"
- When i tried with "my comp. name": "ORA-12154:TNS:Listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA"
- When i tried with "(Local Database)": "ORA-12560:TNS:Protocol Adapter Error"
```

Comment: can you tnsping the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, i solved the problem. Just copy the tnsnames.ora to "@oraclehome\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN" to "@oraclehome\client_1\Network\Admin" and the error message is gone.

> You should restart the listener and the compiler program(For example Visual Studio).